# How to alter cron output e-mail for unique messages on Subject?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron job which runs every 4 hours. When it sends me e-mail in gmail.com of the output, it threads it and makes it hard to look at the most recent message or specific ones.

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * /root/backup.sh #Backup of server
```

Would it be possible to have the Description field in a cron job insert the 'date' commands output so that it not only time stamps it in the Subject but makes it unique so the messages from the same cron job aren't threaded together?

Maybe something like this?
    0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * /root/backup.sh #'Backup of server; date'
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script which does not give any output to *stderr* or *stdout* itself (then `cron` won't send any email).

That script could send emails explicitly, e.g. using `mail -s "some subject"`; and you could also use `logger` to write log messages. You might want something like `mail -s $(date +"backup %D")`

Your `crontab` entry could redirect outputs, e.g. `/root/betterbackup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` and you explicitly ensure in `betterbackup.sh` that appropriate mails and logs are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S"`** in the shell file where you are setting the description of the mail.
see [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-date-command-howto-see-set-date-time/)

If you want to specify `date` in your cron then you can try below syntax

```
0 */4 * * * yourshellscript.sh backup_server_`date +"%Y_%m_%d:%H:%M:%S"`
```

**Remember** if you are using `mail -s "your subject"` kind of mail sending then you have to **escape doublequotes** in the `date` command i mentioned above.
FYR see below

```
mail -s "backup_server_`date +\"%Y_%m_%d:%H:%M:%S\"`" ur_id@example.com < myfile.txt
```

Here **myfile.txt** contains the mail body.

Comment: From webmin doing a 'run' to test it for the cron job, it produces this error:
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: What is webmin? If you want to run it as a shell script you need to add `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script and have to enter a blank new line at the end.

Comment: It ran as normal cron, and produced errors:
bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: can your try with normal cron from comman prompt? and let me know if the crontab was installed correctly. I am using similar kind of thing for creating log files for particualr jobs but i don't get any errors.

Comment: I'd be happy to do that, what do you suggest? The script it's running has been running fine for months. I only started getting the errors after adding the above backup_server_`date +"%Y_%m_%d:%H:%M:%S"`